# Process files from multiple folders in S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have below files in s3:

**Bucket name:** Test

Two folders in bucket Test as folder1 & folder2.

Each folder has multiple files:

- folder1:

  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
- folder2:

  - file3.txt
  - file4.txt

I want to read data from each file, from both folders one by one.

So, 1st pick folder1 and process(read contents of files & save it in a string) both files, then go to folder2 and process(read contents of files & save it in a string) both files.

I'm trying this using boto3.

I am able to get the list of folder/files but cannot process the file.

```
s3conn = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=awsAccessKey, aws_secret_access_key=awsSecretKey)
bucketname = s3conn.Bucket(mys3bucket)

myprefix = "source"

objs = bucketname.objects.filter(Prefix=myprefix)
for object in objs:
    print('{0}:{1}'.format(bucketname.name, object.key))
```

Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please Edit your question and provide more details so that we can assist you? For example, what do you mean by "process both files"? Can you show us some source code you are using to "process files"? What is the problem you are experiencing? What error message are you receiving?

Comment: I want to read the contents of files & save it in a string.

Comment: Please show us the code you are using at the moment to read the file contents and save it, plus any error messages you are receiving. Or, if you are asking which command to use, have a look at [get_object()](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) and [download_file()](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file).